# WPF checkbox Tag is null eventhough it is set in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to make use of the Tag property of the WPF checkbox. This is my XAML:

```
<CheckBox Content="BTC/USD" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="14,0,0,41" 
VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsChecked="True" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Tag="btcusd" 
 Unchecked="CheckBox_Checked"/>
```

When I open my app, `CheckBox_Checked` is called immediately, but the sender's Tag property is null. Why can this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Checked property is set right on the XAML loading, when you set IsChecked="True". The tag may be loaded only later when the XAML loading code decides to set this property. That's why you can see uninitialized properties.

Comment: This is an evil case, where the order of the attributes matter the behavior of the app. I suggest to subscribe the events *after* the control initialization, that is in the C#-behind.

Comment: I try to avoid codebehind as much as possible for designing UI behavior. yes, it was right, the method was called before the tag was set. a simple null check for tag solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

simple Solution for all of these type bugs/errors:

```
1- bool bFormLoaded;//=false ;


2- at [YourWinOrControlorWPF]_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)


add this flag at end of function:
bFormLoaded=true;

3-at UseDefaultFoldersCB_Checked(...)

add this line
 if(bFormLoaded==false) return;
```

100%